# Benchmarking Rust Crypto's AES module

Tags: rust, cryptography, aes, benchmarking

I am trying to benchmark the rust-crypto crate with focus on the AES module in ECB mode and I want to compare the benchmarks to the output of `openssl speed -evp aes-128-ecb`.
The problem is that I reached a performance dead-end with my current Rust code that I am not able to overcome with just compiler optimizations. I am 100% sure that the AES hardware instructions are in use but still my current benchmarks are far behind the output of openssl, as you will see below. I don't really know how to proceed from here, so if someone has any ideas towards optimizing my code for speed (size does not matter), any kind of help is appreciated!

This is the most basic version of my code, it benchmarks the amount of 16-byte blocks I can encrypt with AES-128-ECB in 3 seconds:

```rust
    let mut block = GenericArray::from([0u8; 16]);
    let key = GenericArray::from([0u8; 16]);
    let cipher = Aes128::new(&key);

    let mut counter = 0;
    let end = Duration::from_secs(3);
    let now = Instant::now();
    while now.elapsed() < end {
        cipher.encrypt_block(&mut block);
        counter += 1;
    }
    let time = now.elapsed();
    println!(
        "Doing aes-128-ecb for 3s on {} size blocks: {} aes-128-ecb's in {:.2?}",
        block.len(),
        counter,
        time
    );
```

Here's the definition of my release profile in the `cargo.toml`:

```
[profile.release]
opt-level = 3
debug = false
rpath = false
lto = "fat"
panic = "abort"
debug-assertions = false
codegen-units = 1
```

Here's how I compile the program:

`RUSTFLAGS="-Ctarget-cpu=native --emit=asm" cargo build --release --target=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`

This is the output of `openssl speed -evp aes-128-ecb`:

`Doing aes-128-ecb for 3s on 16 size blocks: 190025974 aes-128-ecb's in 2.99s`

And here is the output of my code:

`Doing aes-128-ecb for 3s on 16 size blocks: 146152536 aes-ecb's in 3.00s`

As you can see there's a difference of ~45 million blocks and I really don't know how to bridge the gap.

Comment: encrypt_block this function looks suspicious. any chance can you test with another implementation of aes ?

Comment: I'd suggest benchmarking with a set number of blocks, instead of a set time limit. It could be that checking the elapsed time between each iteration is adding a lot of overhead.

Comment: @ozkanpakdil Well I mean, I am using the official [Rust Crypto AES library](https://github.com/RustCrypto/block-ciphers/tree/master/aes). It is third party verified to be correct so I don't think there's a problem with the library.

Comment: @PitaJ I will try that! However, I also tried to batch the encryptions to reduce the calls to now.elapsed(), though I wasn't yet able to do it properly, because LLVM keeps optimizing the encryption line away as it "does not really do anything".

Comment: Try compiling with "target-cpu=native" option

Comment: @stepan As specified by my post in the section where I am describing how I compile, I am already doing that.

Comment: @Schmid7k right, sorry I missed that. Upon closer read - the "elapsed" call on every iteration is definitely a problem (not sure if it's the whole reason for perf difference, but it could be). On my system (i7-9750H, macOS) it takes ~35 ns so if I completely removed your AES encryption code and just ran an empty `elapsed` loop - it would do a lot less than your result still.

Comment: If you want LLVM to stop optimizing a result away, pass it through [`std::hint::black_box`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/hint/fn.black_box.html). Note you'll need to use nightly with `#![feature(bench_black_box)]`